# Finishing activities when new activity is started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Supposing I have an Activity Stack like this(from top to bottom):

D - C - B - A

So the activity D is on top of the stack and is currently running (displayed).

Now, from the activity D I want call the activity B (in the second position in the stack), so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

After this operation, the new configuration of the stack, now should be:

B - D - C - B - A

But what I really want is the following stack configuration:

B - A

How can I obtain this result? Is there any FLAG that I can use for this?

Summarizing I want that when I start the activity B (from D) both D and C are automatically finished.

Comment: My app allows also to go back from the D to C, so If I follow your suggestion I can't go back to C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Comment: I was about to write this solution. I have just find it :)

Comment: I know how annoying it is:) Sry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use startactivity for result when starting d and send intent value as "ActivitStarted","D"

onresult

check result activity send d if d send then again start c 
check result activity send c if c send then again start b
check result activity send b if b send then again start a

Answer (score 0):

Call "C" from "D", with a intent variable like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("BYPASS_ME", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityC.java, get the intent value, if its true then finish the activity. Now C will be removed from stack.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "startActivityForResult" and then when you want to "call" activity B you actually "finish" activity D. From there, do a check in Activity C to see what you should do next:

[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

You will want to pay attention to the part where you set data in your intent - that will tell you if you should finish Activity C or something else.

RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED don't tell you much, and also be careful because hitting "back" can result in a null intent (so you can't rely on checking for the contents of the result intent, if that intent is null).

Comment: This is probably the best solution although it will only work if `Activity C` is the only way to start `Activity D`. If you have some other `Activity X` that starts `Activity D` you will have to implement the same logic there as well.

Comment: true. I was answering in the context of the question (the stack order was provided)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no flag to fulfill your requirement.

As Tober said:

What you can do is you just finish C before D and do same when calling the next one.

In my view the first answer is same as tober like call finish in both C and D but now in A when you acivities are going in onPause stage .

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```